# IPtables DNS conflicts

Tags: networking, dns, iptables

On my VPS, when I run

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

It works just fine, but when I do

```
ping google.com
```

it just hangs. The contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by 
resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 108.61.10.10
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

and I know OpenDNS works fine. I think the problem is with iptables, because it was working fine before I changed the iptables settings `iptables -S` is:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 80,443,8080,2222,22,1194,993,25,995,143,110,4433 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m multiport ! --dports 53,1194,500,4500 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 25 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 20/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```

Comment: Are there some other rules in other tables? Mangle, nat, raw? Try allowing `tcp 53` as well.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to `-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m multiport ! --dports 53,1194,500,4500 -j DROP` When I remove that, it works, but I need that line to prevent DDoS attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow source port 53,  `iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT` before `-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m multiport ! --dports 53,1194,500,4500 -j DROP`, as the replies goes from the resolvers source port `53`.

For debugging purpose, attach problematic rule with `-j LOG` target, and you will get a cleaner picture.

However, for a proper firewall - I would recommend to use `POLICY DROP` and allow only desired traffic.